# Pictures not inserting

Tags: graphics, titles, minipage

I am trying to insert a picture using `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`.  I have that in my preamble, and then I'm attempting to insert a picture on a title page.  I use the `\includegraphics` command.  I have the picture saved as a PNG in the file the `.tex` file is saved in.  however, when I try to compile, LaTeX returns a `\includegraphics is not a valid control sequence` error.

I opened a new file and just included the same image, and the image was created.  So why can I not include the picture inside a title page?  Below is my full code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\begin{document} 
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

% Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
% only works if a paragraph has started.

% Title
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Brian and Sara's Cookbook}\\[0.4cm]

\HRule \\[1.5cm]

% Author and supervisor
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\
Brian \textsc{Maleck}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Author:} \\
Sara \textsc{Comer}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\includegraphics{cover.png}
\vfill
% Bottom of the page
{\large \today}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: If I add `demo` option to graphicx (as I don't have the figures) your code runs without error `\includegraphics is not a valid control sequence` is not a LaTeX error message, is it issued by your editor or other checking tool?

Comment: Works fine here.